# If $X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots$ is an i.i.d. sequence, is the sequence of sup's independent?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables. Let
\begin{align*}
Y_{n} = \sup_{k\leq n} X_{k}
\end{align*}
Is the sequence $\{Y_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ a sequence of **independent** random variables? My intuition is no, but can anyone provide either a proof or counterexample?

Comment: Clearly not. For example the $Y_n$ are non decreasing.

Comment: Clearly $E(Y_{n+1} | Y_n) \ge Y_n$. This contradicts independence.

Comment: @HansEngler Why? There exists independent random variables $U$ and $V$ such that $E(U\mid V)\geqslant V$ almost surely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $k\lt j$, then for any $t\in\mathbb R$, 
$$\left\{Y_j\lt t\right\}\cap \left\{Y_k\geqslant t\right\}=\emptyset$$
but *if the distribution of $X_1$ is not degenerated* (that is, $X_1$ is not almost surely equal to a constant), then we can find a $t$ such that $\Pr\left(X_1\leqslant t\right)\notin\left\{0,1\right\}$, which shows that the events $\left\{Y_j\lt t\right\}$ and $\left\{Y_k\geqslant t\right\}$ are not independent.